# Simplex Algorithm

Tags: linear-programming, discrete-optimization

I'm currently trying to implement the (revised) Simplex Algorithm, but according to my notes the LP in standard form $\left( Ax = b, x \geq 0 \right)$ with $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ has to have more or equal variables than contraints ($n \geq m$).

What exactly do i have to do if that's not the case? I would be glad for some help!

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Check page 55 ff

http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~moehring/adm2/adm2-english.pdf

You need a kind of Phase 1.

Comment: Links can decay. You may wish to at least outline the steps.